# ASP.NET 4.5 Web.config Error

Tags: asp.net, webforms, web-config

My Web.config file is structured as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    ...
</configuration>
```

The above works.

When I try to add an appSettings section as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
    </appSettings>
    ...
</configuration>
```

**I get the following error**:

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Error Code     0x8007000d
Config Error       Only one  element allowed. It must be the first child element of the root  element

**UPDATE**

if I place the `<appSettings></appSettings>` section after the `<configSections></configSections>` section, it works! What's happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error message "Config Error Only one element allowed. It must be the first child element of the root element" is referring to the `<configSections>` element.

Per the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228256(v=vs.100).aspx):

> If the **configSections** element is in a configuration file, the
>   **configSections** element must be the first child element of the
>   **configuration** element.

So, `<appSettings>` element will only work when it follows the `<configSections>`, by design.

Comment: Thanks Mike, the MS link on the error page didn't help.